# Check if element is focused with Vanilla JS, not jQuery

Tags: javascript

I have this big class Search, which controls my search bar on my website. Now, when a input is focused, i dont want my `s` key (which pops out the search bar) to execute when a input is focused. I tried with `document.activeElement`, but then, the search bar wont even open, whilst the input not being focused. You can see it, under `keydown` event listener, under Events comment

```js
class Search {
    // Describe and create object
    
    constructor() {
        this.openButton = document.querySelectorAll('.js-search-trigger');
        this.closeButton = document.querySelector('#close-button');
        this.searchOverlay = document.querySelector('.search-overlay'); 
        this.searchField =   document.getElementById('search-term');
        this.typingTimer;
        this.events();
        this.isSpinnerVisible = false;
        this.resultsDiv = document.getElementById('search-overlay__results');
        this.previousValue;
        console.log(this.openButton);
    }
    // Events
    events() {
        this.openButton.forEach(e => {
        e.addEventListener('click', () => {
            this.openOverlay();
            document.body.classList.add('body-no-scroll');
        });
    })
        this.closeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            this.closeOverlay();
            document.body.classList.remove('body-no-scroll');
            
        })
        document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
            if(e.key === 's' && !(this === document.activeElement)){
                this.openOverlay();
                document.body.classList.add('body-no-scroll');
                console.log("s pressed")
            }
             if(e.key === 'Escape' && this.isOverlayOpen){                
                this.closeOverlay();
                document.body.classList.remove('body-no-scroll');
                console.log("esc pressed");
            }
        });
        this.searchField.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
            this.typingLogic();
        })
    }

    // Methods
    openOverlay(){
        this.searchOverlay.classList.add('search-overlay--active');
        this.isOverlayOpen = true;
    }
    closeOverlay(){
        this.searchOverlay.classList.remove('search-overlay--active');
    }
    typingLogic(){
        if(this.searchField.value != this.previousValue){
            clearTimeout(this.typingTimer);
            if(this.searchField.value){
                if(!this.isSpinnerVisible){
                    this.resultsDiv.innerHTML = '<div class="spinner-loader"></div>';
                    this.isSpinnerVisible = true;
                }
                this.typingTimer = setTimeout(this.getResults(),2000);
            }else{
                this.resultsDiv.innerHTML = '';
                this.isSpinnerVisible = false;
            }
            
        }
        
        this.previousValue = this.searchField.value;
    }
    getResults(){
        this.typingTimer = setTimeout(()=> {
            this.resultsDiv.innerHTML = 'Some here';
            this.isSpinnerVisible =false;
        },2000)
    }
}   
 
export default Search
```

Comment: I believe the input you are talking about is SearchField. If that is the case I think it should be !(this.SearchField === document.activeElement) instead of !(this === document.activeElement)

Comment: Maybe if you add the html and make it working as a standalone snippet you'll make life easier to anyone going to answer

Comment: @DiegoDeVita lol, im not gonna add 1000 lines of html

Comment: it's nice to hear you laugh.. next time you ask a question don't even mind writing anything.. just the question mark will be enough!

Comment: @DiegoDeVita Please dont be a smartass, your just doing too much

Comment: please I just asked you to be more detailed so that it was easier to craft a verifiable answer. I really didn't like your response there. I apologize for sounding smartass but it was very rude to hear that when it actually didn't require at all 1000 lines of codes as you said. Asking a question requires some efforts and should be done in a way that's comfortable for people to face your problem and without them inventing something missing just to make it work and see the problem with their own eyes. Luckily someone put the efforts that you lacked and successfully got the correct answer.

Comment: I agree with @DiegoDeVita, @Jovan you should have at least add html with few elements which you have mentioned in `constructor`. Chances of correct answer will get less if you are not able to provide complete verifiable runnable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check `tagName` property of `activeElement`. And if it is not `input` then proceed with your code. Update your condition like below.

```
if(e.key === 's' && document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'input')
```